# Find the value of the following finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> What is the value of the  following **finite** series $$\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n^2}~=~?$$

- I know that the value of the infinite series $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\dfrac 1{i^2}=1+\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\cdots~=~\dfrac{~~\pi^2}{6}~.$$But I am unable to find the value of the series when the number of terms are finite $($say,$~n~)$.

Please help.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to have a convenient closed form.

Comment: These are partial sums of $\zeta(2)$, which have a good approximation, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124881/an-approximation-for-partial-sums-of-zeta-function).

Answer (score 3):

This is given by

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}=\zeta(2)-\zeta(2,n+1)=\zeta(2)-\psi^{(1)}(n+1)$$

in terms of the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) and [trigamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function). Approximations and other forms can be found in the provided links.

Comment: +1 Even though the functions on the RHS are basically defined by the LHS

Answer (score 2):

You can write
$$S_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k^2}=H_n^{(2)}-1$$ and, for large values of $n$
$$S_n=\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-1\right)-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{6
   n^3}+\frac{1}{2 n^4}-\frac{29}{30 n^5}+\frac{3}{2
   n^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$ For $n=10$, the exact value is
$$S_{10}=\frac{698249}{1270080}\approx 0.549767$$ while the above gives
$$\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{6570749}{6000000}\approx 0.549809$$

Comment: What is $~H_n^{(2)}~$here ?

Comment: @nmasanta. generalized harmonic numbers