# How to calculate the sum of the squares of the reciprocals of the first n positive integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

I want to derive the formula for $1/(1^2)+1/(2^2)+...+1/(n^2)$ where $n$ is a positive integer and $n<\infty$. All I could find no the internet dealt with the case where $n$ goes to infinity, and based on those solutions, I'm not even sure that a formula exists for the finite case. I tried deriving it by induction, but failed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unlikely there is a closed form.  As with the Harmonic numbers, there should be useful analytic approximations.  See, e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124881/an-approximation-for-partial-sums-of-zeta-function)

Comment: A first approximation is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac1n$